# How to run "hg update" via mercurial incoming hook

Tags: mercurial-hook

What is the correct way of running `hg update` in an incoming hook?

Is it:

```
[hooks]
incoming.foo = hg update
```

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972409/call-a-mercurial-command-hg-update-from-a-python-hook)

Or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F) makes this suggestion:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update
```

> This goes in .hg/hgrc on the remote repository

So, indeed, this is the simple and correct way of doing it. Your example used `incoming`, but that hook runs once for every single changeset. The `changegroup` hook is done once after all changes have been pulled in, so I think it may suit your needs better.

If you end up needing more control, you can create an in-process hook script to fulfill those needs. The Wiki has some [good examples](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HookExamples).